# This is calling more than 1 function onclick in javascript, what is the best practice to use, querySelector or getElementbyClass?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, dom-events, buttonclick

Please check my codes below. Right now, I used `document.querySelector()`. I was wondering if we consider the best practice, should I use `document.getElementsByClassName()`?

```js
const txt = document.querySelector('.ourText');

function changeColor() {
  txt.style.color = 'white';
}

function changeBackground() {
  txt.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}

function fontSizeLarge() {
  txt.style.fontSize = '30px';
}
```

```html
<div class="ourBox">
  <p class="ourText">This is a paragraph!</p>
  <button onclick="changeColor(); changeBackground(); fontSizeLarge()">Add More functions</button>
</div>
```

So for the `document.querySelector`, it means that we're going to search in this document (document.)that's the command. So basically JavaScript understands we need to search this HTML document.   The query means search for a selector and in this case, a class with the name ourText.

I think the div class name ourBox is also not necessary.

I will continue learning the DOM Selectors, as the name suggests is used to select HTML elements within a document using JavaScript. I understand that there are 5 ways in which you can select elements in a DOM using selectors. Sometimes, I am just confused about the best practices. There are so many different approaches.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select multiple elements you should use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`.

There are some tests over internet that implies `getElementsByClassName` is slightly faster than `querySelectorAll` but there isn't any significant performance difference between them and I think overthinking about choosing one would be over optimizing unless some special situations.

Benchmark: https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/393/0/queryselector-vs-getelementsbyclassname

Also `querySelector` & `querySelectorAll` can handle more complicated queries and you can use all CSS selectors with it like `id`, `class`, descendants selector, attribute selector and etc.

It's better to use `addEventListener` instead of `onClick` event and put your javascript code in an external JS file because:

1. It helps in the reusability of code in more than one HTML file.
2. It allows easy code readability.
3. It is time-efficient as web browsers cache the external js files,
   which further reduces the page loading time.
4. It enables both web designers and coders to work with html and js
   files parallelly and separately, i.e., without facing any code
   conflictions.
5. The length of the code reduces as only we need to specify the
   location of the JS file.

Example:

JS file

```
const txt = document.querySelector('.ourText');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
    
function changeColor() {
    txt.style.color = 'white';
}

function changeBackground() {
    txt.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}

function fontSizeLarge() {
    txt.style.fontSize = '30px';
}

const buttonClickHandler = () => {
    changeColor();
    changeBackground();
    fontSizeLarge();
}

btn.addEventListener('click', buttonClickHandler);
```

HTML file

```
<div>
  <p class="ourText">This is a paragraph!</p>
  <button id="btn">Add More functions</button>
</div>
```

for further info about external javascript: [https://www.javatpoint.com/external-javascript-file#:~:text=Advantages%20of%20External%20JavaScript&text=It%20allows%20easy%20code%20readability,without%20facing%20any%20code%20conflictions](https://www.javatpoint.com/external-javascript-file#:%7E:text=Advantages%20of%20External%20JavaScript&text=It%20allows%20easy%20code%20readability,without%20facing%20any%20code%20conflictions).

You don't do anything with ourBox class name so yeah it's not necessary.

And last thing I want to say is that it's better to not use CSS code in JS too. you can move your CSS styles to CSS files with some selectors like IDs or classes and then with JS toggle, add or remove that selector. Like this:

CSS file:

```
.alert--danger {
   background-color: red;
}
```

JS file:

```
const txt = document.querySelector('.ourText');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

const buttonClickHandler = () => {
    txt.classList.toggle('alert--danger');
}

btn.addEventListener('click', buttonClickHandler);
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much, Davood. I appreciate the information.